# Symfony2 Ignores locale for translation

Tags: symfony, twig

I have an Symfony **2.8** and I am using the translation feature to make my app multilingual.

I am using the `trans` extension method of `Twig` to call for translation.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
{{ 'Example' | trans }}
```

And the translated values are in a file in `Resources` dir.

`messages.it.yml`

This file is for the Italian locale.

My problem is that the app always uses the translated values no matter the value locale.

I test the locale with `{{ app.request.locale }}` and it value changes normally.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable the translator in `app/config.yml`:

```
framework:
    translator:      { fallback: %locale% }
```

Then you should put your `messages.it.yml` in `app/Resources/translations/` or in your bundle's `AppBundle/Resources/translations` but not in any `Resources` directory directly.